# Orientable surface $M\subset\mathbb{R^{m+n}}$ such that has no normal linearly independent vector fields

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds, surfaces, non-orientable-surfaces

We know the following results:

**Theorem 1:** If a suface $M^m \subset \mathbb{R}^{m+n}$ of co-dimension $n$ admits $n$ linearly independent continuous normal vector fields $v_1, \dots, v_n:M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m+n}$ then $M$ is orientable.

Also, the converse of the above result is true if the co-dimension of $M$ is one, more precisely:

**Theorem 2:** Every orientable surface $M$ of co-dimension $1$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ admits a normal continuous non-vanishing vector field.

**My question:** I would like to know a example of a orientable surface $M \subset \mathbb{R}^{m+n}$ of co-dimension $n>1$ which has no vector fields $v_1, \dots, v_n$ satisfying the properties of the first Theorem 1.

Comment: There's a typo in Theorem 1. You need the vector fields to be *linearly independent*.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thank you! These results are a little bit complicated for me, could you provide some reference for the results you mentioned?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Would it be possible to give a direct proof, using only real analysis results, surfaces, etc?